# How to import variables in jinja2

Tags: python, variables, flask, jinja2

I am trying to show the name of the user when the user log in and redirecting him to dashboard.
I have passed the variable in /dashboard route but the user name is visible only in dashboard page.
And when I route to different page eg., Home then the name of the user is not showing.
I want to show the logged in user name in all pages but the user name is visible only in dashboard.

Here is the code from app.py

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.user_name)
```

and this is my layout.html

```
<div class="account-info">
     {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
     <span id="account-name"><a href="/dashboard">{{ name }}</a></span>
     {% else %}
     <span id="account-name"><a href="/dashboard">{{ dname }}</a></span>
     {% endif %}
</div>
```

here dname is the variable I am passing if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using Session. Once your app captures and verifies the user you can store the username using session to allow it to be available across requests.

Please refer to this documentation:
[Flask Documentation on Session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions)

Answer (score -1):

### First Try This

You are only passing in the `Username` class, try passing in the whole class as well.

Next you can create a new route for autheticated users called `home_auth` or something like that and over ride the default home page to `home_auth` page.

In the `home_auth` page, you can pass in the `Username` and display it.

Comment: But I don't have any Username class,  user_name is the field in my database of class User.

Comment: Is it hosted on github? if so, can you send me the link?

Comment: No, its not hosted on github

Comment: Is there any way you can send the layout.html and app.py, maybe as a gist or a image?

Comment: Sorry, but I am working on a project and don't want to expose my code. Plz, show me another way to solve my problem.

Comment: This should work. But if it doesn't please do comment. Sorry for asking for the code to solve. That was not professional.

See below examples:

https://i.imgur.com/nw1mEMA.png

https://i.imgur.com/KeBxPKU.png